# Having trouble downloading oracle sql

Tags: java, macos, oracle

I run on OS X 10.5.8 and am trying to download Django IDE. Before I download Django i tried to download  Oracle SQL workbench which requires the latest version of JDK 7. My os does not meet the requirements to download JDK 7 (os x 10.7.4 and up), how can I get around this?

Comment: Django is not an IDE. And you don't need workbench to use Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I suspect that the OP means [this thing](https://github.com/lusob/django-ide).

Comment: `trying to download Django IDE` what it has to do with installing JDK? Seems that these two things are not connected.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySQL Workbench download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/), there is a link in the bottom right corner that says

```
Looking for previous GA versions?
```

If you click that you can find a download link for version 5.2 of the Workbench, which should depend on an earlier version of Java. Unfortunately, the details of these dependencies are very hard to locate, so you may have to try it and see what happens.

Comment: The older version you recommended downloads successfully, but every time I attempt to open it pops up with a message that "the application MySQLworkbench quit unexpectedly" Thank you for help and patience.

Comment: @user3106014, try running it from the terminal and see if there are any useful error messages.